# Nombre de columna no válido

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Estoy intentando conectar una interfaz gráfica creada con java con una base de datos de oracle.
Tengo *ClaseBBDD.java* para las consultas, *InterfazGrafica.java* para la interfaz y *DialogoEstadisticas.java* que implementa el action listener.

Éste es el método que me da problemas del código de *ClaseBBDD.java*:

```
   // Devuelve un string con las estadísticas de los jugadores del equipo elegido
   // Introducirá un título:
   // NOMBRE(hueco de 22, alineado a la izquierda)REBOTES(hueco de 10, alineado a la derecha)TAPONES(hueco de 10, alineado a la derecha)
   // Luego los datos, uno por línea con el mismo formato
   // Consulta:
   // SELECT round(AVG(rebotes_por_partido), 2), round (AVG(tapones_por_partido),2), jugadores.nombre FROM estadisticas 
   // INNER JOIN jugadores ON jugadores.codigo = estadisticas.jugador 
   // INNER JOIN equipos ON jugadores.nombre_equipo = equipos.nombre 
   // WHERE equipos.nombre = ? 
   // GROUP BY jugadores.nombre
   // jugadores.nombre es una cadena de caracteres
   // round(AVG(rebotes_por_partido), 2) y round (AVG(tapones_por_partido),2) números decimales
   public String selectEstadisticas(String equipoElegido) throws SQLException {
      // Creamos la conexión con el método conexion()
      Connection conn = conexion();
      
      // Creamos una consulta preparada para insertar los datos
      String consulta = "SELECT round(AVG(rebotes_por_partido), 2), round (AVG(tapones_por_partido),2), jugadores.nombre FROM estadisticas "
                        + "INNER JOIN jugadores ON jugadores.codigo = estadisticas.jugador "
                        + "INNER JOIN equipos ON jugadores.nombre_equipo = equipos.nombre "
                        + "WHERE equipos.nombre = ? "
                        + "GROUP BY jugadores.nombre";
                        
      PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
      
      // Introducimos en la consulta el valor recibido como parámetro y la ejecutamos
      stat.setString(1, equipoElegido);
      ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
      
      // Procesamos el resultado y lo guardamos en un String
      String resultado = String.format("%-22s", "NOMBRE") + String.format("%10s", "REBOTES") + String.format("%10s", "TAPONES") + "\n";
      while (rs.next()) {
         resultado += String.format("%-22s", rs.getString("jugadores.nombre"))
                      + String.format("%10f", rs.getDouble("round(AVG(rebotes_por_partido), 2)"))
                      + String.format("%10f", rs.getDouble("round (AVG(tapones_por_partido),2)")) + "\n";
      }
      
      conn.close();
      return resultado;
   }
```

Me he dado cuenta de que el problema está aquí:

```
while (rs.next()) {
        resultado += String.format("%-22s", rs.getString("jugadores.nombre"))
                     + String.format("%10f", rs.getDouble("round(AVG(rebotes_por_partido), 2)"))
                     + String.format("%10f", rs.getDouble("round (AVG(tapones_por_partido),2)")) + "\n";
     }
```

He intentado arreglarlo poniendo un alias a `jugadores.nombre` o quitando `jugadores.nombre`. Seguramente sea una tontería pero me estoy comiendo la cabeza y no encuentro la solución.

Comment: Ponle alias a cada una de las columnas. La consulta te será más sencilla de leer, y te evitarás esos tipos de errores.

Comment: He puesto alias a todos y me ha funcionado. Gracias a padaleiana.
Ais, los profesores.